# Creating Zip returns read error

Tags: php, file, php-7, php-ziparchive

I have these few lines that create an empty zip file that I will put things in.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$generatedname = uniqid().'.zip';
$res = $zip->open('tmp/'.$generatedname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

`$res` is 5, which corresponds with a read error, and when I go to add files I get an error that the zip is not initialized. This code works on my local machine but not on my iis server, so it's some kind of configuration error?

I can read and write files with fopen and fwrite, so I don't think is has to do with rw permissions, so I'm kinda out of troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: Try adding a file and then closing it anyways. (To my understanding you cannot just create an empty zip)

Comment: @Xedret I mentioned I cannot add files to it. The exact error is:
Message:  ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually figured this one out.
The issue is actually with where the zip is being created. I had it set to `/tmp` in my working directory since I was going to have the file downloaded and then immediately deleted.

So I found [this](https://bnks.xyz/avoiding-permissions-problems-creating-zip-files-php/) article that talks about using a directory the will always be writable by php, so creating my zip file in the system temp directory seems to have done the trick. Heres the updated code:

```
chdir( sys_get_temp_dir() );

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$generatedname = uniqid().'.zip';
$zip->open($generatedname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```